# PHP Repeat loop until no matching record

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, reference

I have one table that contains :

```
TICKET  | VOLUME | REFF
------------------------
111111  | 1      | 
111112  | 0.5    | 111111
111113  | 2      | 
111114  | 1      | 111112
111115  | 4      | 111114
111116  | 2      | 111113
111117  | 1      | 111116
and so on..
```

The result that i want to show (in array format) is:

```
[
    [ 'TICKET' => 111112, 'VOLUME' => 0.5 ],
    [ 'TICKET' => 111114, 'VOLUME' => 1 ],
    [ 'TICKET' => 111115, 'VOLUME' => 4 ]
]
```

So, all the answers are parenting to ticket no. 11111.
How to do it?

Many thanks!

What i've tried so far :

```
$parent_ticket = 111111;
$res = [];

   $cek = DB::table('data_ticket')->where('ticket', $parent_ticket)->first();

   if($cek){
       $cek_child1 = DB::table('data_ticket')->where('ticket', $cek->REFF)->first();

       if($cek_child1){
          $res[] = [ 'TICKET' => $cek_child1->TICKET, 'VOLUME' => $cek_child1->VOLUME ];
          $cek_child2 = DB::table('data_ticket')->where('ticket', $cek_child1->REFF)->first();

          if($cek_child2){
             $res[] = [ 'TICKET' => $cek_child2->TICKET, 'VOLUME' => $cek_child2->VOLUME ];
             $cek_child3 = DB::table('data_ticket')->where('ticket', $cek_child2->REFF)->first();

             if($cek_child3){
                // and so on....
             }

          }
       }
   }
```

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: It is if condition for Ref if null do nothing else set the array of two items index zero is TICKET and index 1 is VOLUME

Comment: i've tried search manually until 10 times, how to make automatically until no child available?

Comment: @Osama thanks for the answer, i was wrong, i've edited the question, there's no null data except the parents.

Comment: Why don't you post the code that you have tried?

Comment: Yes, i did. i asks the question in here because i don't find any answer. could you give me some tutorials or link to the tutorials?

Comment: Why don't you just post the answer if you know the answer? @Difster

Comment: Because if you're going to learn to do this, you should work most of it out yourself, that would be more beneficial to you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use recursion, this is the easiest way to do what you want.

```
<?php

$parent_ticket = 111111;
$res = [];

$cek = DB::table('data_ticket')->where('ticket', $parent_ticket)->first();

if ($cek) {
    findAllTicketsAndReferences($cek, $res);
}

function findAllTicketsAndReferences($cek, array &$res)
{
    $cek_child1 = DB::table('data_ticket')->where('ticket', $cek->REF)->first();

    if (!$cek_child1) {
        return false;
    }

    $res[] = ['TICKET' => $cek_child1->TICKET, 'VOLUME' => $cek_child1->VOLUME];

    findAllTicketsAndReferences($cek_child1, $res);
}
```

This should work, the idea is to return false when there's no child anymore, otherwise it goes on and changes the array of datas.

Comment: Yes, you got my point! Thanks, i will mark this one as accepted answer first before i try it.